# Webpack issue with a python file

Tags: javascript, python, webpack, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a node.js project using webpack that's being deployed to AWS Lambda. However, I also have a single python file in the project that's powering one of the Lambda functions (i ported a legacy python script over to lambda for automation purposes). In my serverless.yml, I've set the appropriate runtimes (node.js/python) for the functions.

My problem is that webpack throws errors about my python file (it's even referencing a python/handler.js file that doesnt exist - the python handler is python/handler.py).

The exact error is:
ERROR in ./python/handler.py 2:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

I just want webpack to bundle the regular .js files, and leave the python file alone. Note that deploying the project without webpack works, and gives me lambda functions powered by javascript and python. Does anyone have any suggestions to my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `**/*.py` to your `excludeFiles` block.

```
custom:
  webpack:
    excludeFiles: **/*.py # Provide a glob for files to ignore
```

You can read more in the [documentation](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack#configure)

Side note - you may consider trying `es-build` instead, which is often 10x faster than webpack. You can read more [here](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-esbuild)

Comment: when I add `excludeFiles: '**/*.py'` I get the error: `ServerlessError: No matching handler found for...` and my function has a handler. Do you need to change something in webpack config file as well?